# Need to modify BE response to expected response at FE

Tags: javascript, recursion

BE Response:- which I am getting from Backend Service

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "AnyType",
    "resources": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "treeId": "1",
        "name": "name1",
        "description": "description1",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "treeId": "1-3",
            "name": "subName1",
            "description": "subDescription1",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 6,
                "treeId": "1-3-6",
                "name": "subSubName1",
                "description": "subSubDesc1",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "treeId": "2",
        "name": "name2",
        "description": "description2",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 7,
            "treeId": "2-7",
            "name": "subName2",
            "description": "subDescription2",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I need to modify this response to as below on FE
Expected Response:- means I need to join name and description field text to one(in name field ) as below:-

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "AnyType",
    "resources": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "treeId": "1",
        "name": "name1-description1",
        "description": "description1",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "treeId": "1-3",
            "name": "subName1-subDescription1",
            "description": "subDescription1",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 6,
                "treeId": "1-3-6",
                "name": "subSubName1-subSubDesc1",
                "description": "subSubDesc1",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "treeId": "2",
        "name": "name2-description2",
        "description": "description2",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 7,
            "treeId": "2-7",
            "name": "subName2-subDescription2",
            "description": "subDescription2",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

there could be n number of children of each object and children can have an array of objects.

What I have done:- I am able to change the very first name but not children name

```
   let resDataArry = [];
    let descData: DynamicResource;
       response.forEach((x, index) => {
    const descName = x.name + ' ' + x.description;
    descData = { ...tree.resources[index], name: descName };
    resDataArry.push(descData);
    });
    return resDataArry;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to access `children` array and then concatenate the `name` and `description` together.

```js
let data = {
  "data": {
    "type": "AnyType",
    "resources": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "treeId": "1",
        "name": "name1",
        "description": "description1",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "treeId": "1-3",
            "name": "subName1",
            "description": "subDescription1",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 6,
                "treeId": "1-3-6",
                "name": "subSubName1",
                "description": "subSubDesc1",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "treeId": "2",
        "name": "name2",
        "description": "description2",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 7,
            "treeId": "2-7",
            "name": "subName2",
            "description": "subDescription2",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
data.data.resources.forEach(function(item){
    item.name = item.name + ' ' + item.description;
    item.children.forEach(function(child){
        child.name = child.name + ' ' + child.description;
    });
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing answer. item.name and child.name can not be change as they are readonly property of Object check console error. And Data is not as per expected response.